# WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment and the requested URL was not found on the server

Tags: python

With hello.py it is working "Hello word".
But when I run the app (webhook_weather.py) it is not working, I am getting following error:
I have

```
set FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_APP= webhook_weather.py
flask run

(helloworld-x2biACXm) C:\Users\Jayanth\Desktop\helloworld>python webhook_weather.py
Starting app on port 80
• Serving Flask app 'webhook_weather' (lazy loading)
• Environment: development
• Debug mode: on
• Restarting with stat
Starting app on port 80
• Debugger is active!
• Debugger PIN: 119-286-619
• Running on all addresses.
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
• Running on http://192.168.43.87:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

192.168.43.87 - - [04/Jun/2021 14:38:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I am not able to open the app page. I will get the page as shown below:

> Not Found
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

When I run the python file, I am getting the AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\Jayanth.virtualenvs\helloworld-CPu4KsHf\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2088, in call
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\Jayanth.virtualenvs\helloworld-CPu4KsHf\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Jayanth.virtualenvs\helloworld-CPu4KsHf\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Jayanth.virtualenvs\helloworld-CPu4KsHf\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Jayanth.virtualenvs\helloworld-CPu4KsHf\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Jayanth.virtualenvs\helloworld-CPu4KsHf\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
File "D:\ExcelSoft\venil\Cognitive-Behavioural-Chatbot-master\helloworld\web.py", line 26, in webhook
res = processRequest(req)
File "D:\ExcelSoft\venil\Cognitive-Behavioural-Chatbot-master\helloworld\web.py", line 36, in processRequest
print ("starting processRequest...",req.get("result").get("action"))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

I tried with: http://localhost/webhook

Comment: You'll need to show the code in `webhook_weather.py` too. If it has no route for `/`, you'll get a 404.

Comment: Also, you have a typo in the first environment variable. It's `FLASK_ENV`, not `FASK_ENV`.

Comment: Yes it is FLASK_ENV , typo mistake ..

Comment: These are the app route,  @app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST']) ; @app.route('/test', methods=['GET']) ; and @app.route('/static_reply', methods=['POST']) .

Comment: There is no `helloworld/web.py` in the repository you had linked earlier.

Comment: Yes, I just renamed webhook_weather.py to web.py

Answer (score 0):

> These are the app route,
> `@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])`
> `@app.route('/test', methods=['GET']`
> `@app.route('/static_reply', methods=['POST'])`

With those routes, attempting to navigate to http://localhost/ will indeed return a 404; nothing's routed to `/`.

Try http://localhost/test instead...

Comment: With this http://localhost/test , I am getting output as "Hello there my friend !!"

Comment: That's probably what the `/test` route does. Is that not what you expected?

Comment: I tried with http://localhost/test , I am getting output as "Hello there my friend !!" This part is working , But if I use http://192.168.43.87:80/ I am getting 404. How do I use the full program (app)? @app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST']) ; @app.route('/static_reply', methods=['POST']) .  Here is the link relevant to the chatbots: https://github.com/avirupm97/Cognitive-Behavioural-Chatbot

Comment: What do you want to do in particular? The webhook_weather.py file in the repo you linked only has some code to get a location's weather as a webhook response, none of the detection or chatbot stuff outlined in the PDF.

Comment: /test route is working, but what about  /webhook and /static_reply ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you pasted in that stuff about a chatbot. The /webhook and /static_reply routes require POST data in some format from some likely external service.

Comment: Ok, what should I do next? How do I get the POST data ? In which format and from which external source? I have sent you the github link.

Comment: Yes, I saw the GitHub link, but the documents there don't tell. The repository is very incomplete and doesn't implement half of the stuff talked about in the PDF or Powerpoint. You'd need to be in touch with the authors, I think.

Comment: I changed the app route,
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST']) to
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
and I am getting the AttributeError: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
File "C:\Users\Jayanth.virtualenvs\helloworld-CPu4KsHf\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2088, in call
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response) and app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e) and app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()

Comment: Changing it to allow GET won't help you at all, since it expects a JSON object to be POSTed. It would then use that object to fetch weather information. I really don't know what you expect to happen here.